# android alarmManager setRepating time delay problem

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to send a notification with the alarm manager in my application. I am using the setRepeating method because it should be in intervals. but notifications always come delayed.
For example, I would like to receive a notification at 12:14. but notification is coming sometimes 12:17, sometimes 12:20

Thanks in advance

Note: doze mode off

For Example:

thatDay Sat Apr 25 16:30:00 GMT+03:00 2020

today Sat Apr 25 16:07:44 GMT+03:00 2020

thatDay.getTimeInMillis() = 1587821400000

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (notification) {
        Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        int today_month_day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int today_month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int today_year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        thatDay.setTime(new Date(0));

        thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, today_month_day);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, today_month);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, today_year);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 23 && calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 7) {
            if (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) < 30) {
                thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                thatDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            } else {
                thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1);
            }
        } else if (thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis() < 0) {
            thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, today_month_day + 1);
        } else {
            thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, today_month_day);
        }


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("NotificationID", 6);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 7, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Objects.requireNonNull(alarmManager).setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, thatDay.getTimeInMillis(), waterList[waterCheck], pendingIntent);


    super.onStop();


}
```

```
   @SuppressLint("BatteryLife")
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
   private void requestBattery() {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       String packageName = context.getPackageName();
       PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
       if (!(Objects.requireNonNull(pm).isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))) {
           intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
           intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
           startActivityForResult(intent, BATTERY_PERMISSION);
       }
   }
```

Comment: share the log having value of ```thatDay.getTimeInMillis()```.

Comment: `thatDay Sat Apr 25 16:30:00 GMT+03:00 2020`

`today Sat Apr 25 16:07:44 GMT+03:00 2020`

Comment: I just got a new log
**thatDay.getTimeInMillis() =1587821400000**

Comment: Please confirm that date and obtained after converting this value is same as your alarm date and time. You can use this website to convert https://currentmillis.com/

Comment: @xaif yes already, i am checking from this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because setRepeating is only fired, when something else is happening in the background. Mainly this is due to battery saving. The best way to set a repeating alarm is to use setExact and set another alarm once the first one was fired.

Alarmmanager:

```
public class AlarmManagerSetup {

public static Boolean alarmActivated;
public static Long milliSeconds;

public void startAlarm(Calendar c, Context context, Database database) {

    android.app.AlarmManager alarmManager = (android.app.AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, 0);

    c.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);

    //compares to the current time and only adds when it is later than now
    if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And inside the Alert Receiver you do this:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        CalendarSearch calendar = new CalendarSearch(context);
        calendar.calendar();

        NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nb = notificationHelper.getChannelNotification(appContext);
        notificationHelper.getManager().notify(1, nb.build());

        AlarmManagerSetup alarmManager = new AlarmManagerSetup();

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        milliSeconds = c.getTimeInMillis();

        alarmManager.startAlarm(c, appContext, database);

}
```

Comment: but I turned off the doze mode.

Comment: this doesn't matter. it is not possible to use setRepeating with exact time anymore! You have to do the work around I mentioned above

Comment: So what path do I have to follow for the interval? my application also determines the range that the user wants. so the notification can choose to come in half an hour, once an hour, once every two hours..how and where should i do this

Comment: You simply take the interval and add this to your desired time. Above the interval is one day (c.add(Calendar.Date, 1). You can also use minutes, seconds etc. 
        tomorrow.add(Calendar.MINUTE, "your interval");
        tomorrow.add(Calendar.SECOND, "your interval");

Comment: I use a very different system. please review. If the application exit is 13:24, I am sending the first notification at 13:30. If the exit time is 13:46, the first notification comes at 14:00.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? @Noiling

Comment: Can you kindly mark my answer as correct? Then we will find a solution.

Comment: Well I marked it as you say but your current answer didn't work for me..

Comment: I think it would be the easiest way for you if you create one activity for the alarmmanager, one for the notification and one for the alert receiver. Otherwise this is not working.